# java сравнение дат

Tags: java, datetime

Подскажите какие существуют варианты сравнения текущей даты и, например, даты окончания срока действия сертификата. Необходимо построить условие(если срок действия сертификата истёк), а в каком виде сравнивать не могу понять.

```
Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        System.out.println("Годен до: " + formatter.format(cert.getNotAfter())); // Годен до: 28.09.2021

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(dtf.format(now));    //05.11.2020
```

В чистом виде данные приходят:

```
Сертификат:    Годен до: Tue Sep 28 17:45:36 NOVT 2021
Текущее время:    2020-11-05T12:35:41.362034200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ это перевести обе даты в миллисекунды и сравнить их значения. Если текущее время больше чем датах истечение срока сертификата, значит он истек.

Но есть разные библиотеки которые могут это делать под капотом.

Comment: Да, так и сделал `if (System.currentTimeMillis() > cert.getNotAfter().getTime() ) {
                System.out.println("Сертификат просрочен");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Сертификат не просрочен");
            }`